# Boost.Spirit.Qi - Errors at the beginning of a rule

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

How would I detect an error at the start of a rule? For example, consider the [Mini XML example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___error_handling.html) included in the docs. If I feed the parser something like:

```
<element>this is an error<element>
```

Then I get:

> Error! Expecting  here: ""
>
> Error! Expecting  here: ""
>
> Parsing failed.

That's fine, but then consider feeding it:

```
element>this is an error</element>
```

And I get the very generic and not so useful:

> Parsing failed.

How could I modify the rule to report the error in an informative way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd want to *require* an element at the document root level.

The other messages are generated by failed *expectation points*. You'll want an extra *expectation point* at the start. I'd do this:

1. rename old `xml` rule to `element`
2. create a new `xml` rule that has the element at an expectation point:

   ```
       xml = qi::eps > element;
   ```
3. [Don't change anything else]
4. ***profit!***

The output becomes:

```
Error! Expecting <element> here: "element>this is a test</element>
"
-------------------------
Parsing failed
-------------------------
```

See [it live here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c491e0bbf934c0afc53297a77ac274c9-0290fe5c6d0997ceafc0a57b47e242ca)

Comment: Note: in spirit X3 just use `x3::expect[]`