# boost::spirit: cause match failure with specific message from semantic action?

Tags: c++, parsing, c++11, boost, boost-spirit

I'm trying to extend an existing use of Boost::spirit implementing a configuration language (with Boost 1.55.0).

If a rule or token fails to match, then the Boost system happily takes care of throwing an `expectation_failure` exception that I can use to complain about where in the nested set of configuration files the error was encountered.

However, there are several clauses where a semantic action consists of something like:

```
[ phx::bind(map_insert_table, qi::_1, ref(tbl), _val) ]
```

where `map_insert_table()` is a function I define which might have an exception condition. If I simply throw my own C++ exception I will abort processing of the file with a meaningful error message, but I will have no way to tell the user the location of their error. If I simply set `_pass` to false per [boost spirit semantic action parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066701/boost-spirit-semantic-action-parameters), then the user will know where the error occurred, but not be given the information we have as to what was actually wrong.

I appreciate the information in that linked question regarding the context, but I don't see how it can help me here, nor how I would access it from the semantic action as phrased above.

I also appreciate that I might be told I'm not using the system in the best way -- that may be true, and I can make incremental changes, but rewriting our whole use of Boost::spirit would be very much a solution of last resort.

All answers appreciated. If more information is needed for my question to be answered (this is my first post after years of lurking) I will certainly try to provide it.

Comment: I'd personally consider the context object an implementation detail and don't recommend piggy-backing on it - probably just because it confuses me (and it's not part of public documentation AFAIK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using references inside the phoenix actor. You can use the same method to store error information somewhere "out-of-band".

Alternatively, you might store optional diagnostics information as part of the attribute type.

Comment: True @sehe (and thank you for your interest), but I was hoping there was a mechanism within the Boost system to do this already. It's cumbersome to pass the information all the way back up to the top-level parser object which can turn the error location into something meaningful for the user, but it is possible and I will do just that if there is no, "nice" way of doing it within the Boost::spirit framework.

Comment: Nicer than what? Nicer than `qi::locals`? Nicer than `phx::ref(this->grammer_member)`? Nicer than `qi::on_error`? Nicer than `iter_pos`? I'm not sure where the "It's cumbersome" peaks in your experience. For me expectation points are plenty fine. I can get the position out of the position iterators from an `expectation_failure<It>` exception. I don't mind putting a string containing the reason into a grammar instance variable.

Comment: By the way, this question reminded me of [this older question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19240806/85371); That's a weak match though. Consider this for background reading: **[access position iterator from semantic actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612657/boostspirit-access-position-iterator-from-semantic-actions/19613827#19613827)**. It's my recommended solution for passing source position down with the Ast nodes.