# Boost::Spirit - on_error not printing

Tags: c++, parsing, error-handling, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to use the `on_error` mechanism of Boost::Spirit::qi to find out why the parsing failed.

I've set a breakpoint at the `on_error` function and the function is being called, but no output (nada, nothing, void, ...).

The simple `on_error`:

```
on_error<fail>(level1,
    boost::phoenix::ref(std::cout) << "I've failed.\n"
    );
```

The complex `on_error` (from various sites):

```
on_error<fail>
(
    start,
    boost::phoenix::ref(std::cout)
        << val("Error! Expecting ")
        << _4
        << val(" here: \"")
        << construct<std::string>(qi::_3, qi::_2)
        << val("\"")
        << std::endl
    );
```

Here is my class containing the simple `on_error`:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
struct Event_Compound
    : qi::grammar<Iterator, Skipper>
{
    Event_Compound () 
        : Event_Compound::base_type(start, "Compound-Event")
        {
            using qi::lexeme;
            using qi::lit;
            using namespace qi;
            using boost::spirit::ascii::char_;

            relational_operator =
                lit("&&")[Matched_Relational_AND]
                || lit("||")[Matched_Relational_OR]
                ;

            compound =
                level1[Matched_Nested_Level1_Begin] >> relational_operator[Matched_Relational_Operator] >> level1[Matched_Nested_Level1_End]
                ;

            compare_or_compound =
                compound[Matched_Compound] | grammar_comparison_event[Matched_Comparison_Event]
                ;

            level1 =
                grammar_boolean_event[Matched_Boolean_Event]
                | ( char_('(')[Matched_Open_Paren] >> compare_or_compound[Matched_Compare_Or] >> char_(')')[Matched_Close_Paren]  )
                ;

            start =
                level1[Matched_Level1_Begin] >> relational_operator[Matched_Relational_Operator] >> level1[Matched_Level1_End]
                ;
            on_error<fail>(level1,
                boost::phoenix::ref(std::cout) << "I've failed.\n"
                );
        }

    Event_Boolean<Iterator, Skipper>        grammar_boolean_event;
    Event_Comparison<Iterator, Skipper>     grammar_comparison_event;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper>             level1;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper>             compound;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper>             compare_or_compound;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper>             relational_operator;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper>             start;
};
```

Is there a *simple* method to trace the behavior or thinking pattern of the parser? (Such as setting a preprocessor macro or some flag variable)

Why isn't there any output from the `on_error`?

Also, what do `_1, _2, _3` and `_4` reference?

I'm trying to debug a grammar and I have output as to the rules that have been matched, but when a rule isn't matched, I want to know which rule and why.

I'm using:

- Boost 1.57.0
- Visual Studio 2010
- Windows 7

Researched:

- [how to make error handling work for
  boost::spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375766/how-to-make-error-handling-work-for-boostspirit)
- [Dispatching on Expectation
  Failures](http://boost-spirit.com/home/2011/02/28/dispatching-on-expectation-point-failures/comment-page-1/)
- [Boost::Spirit documentation: Mini XML - Error
  Handling](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___error_handling.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error handling only relates to expectation points. You don't seem to have any of those.

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/expect.html

To debug the grammar use

- `#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG`  before any boost includes
- `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(node)` or `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((node1)(node2)...)` to select nodes for debug

This will show you the backtracking (if any) and attribute propagation in action. If you use them, locals and inherited attributes will also be shown.

Note your rule's attributes need to be fusion-adapted/streamable for debug to work.

Comment: (About the debug macros, I have numerous answers in [tag boost-spirit](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a85371%20boost_spirit_debug) that shows how to use it, in case you want samples)

Comment: The debug macros were more helpful than the error handling.  I wish they would put the macros into the tutorial. :-)